# Can two foldexpr coexist in my .vimrc?

Tags: vim, folding

1) I have in my .vimrc a fold expr (cf. the third example under the :help fold-expr section) which makes a fold out of paragraphs separated by blank lines :

```
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$'&&getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S'?'<1':1
```

Most of my files are files with paragraphs (to begin with my .vimrc)

2) But I have two or three text files which are simply lists with no paragraphs and I would like to be able to fold everything except for matches to my search. I found in Vim Wikia (Tip 282) the following "Simple Folding" (at the bottom of the Tip's page) which I would like to implement :

```
:set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)!~@/
:nnoremap <F8> :set foldmethod=expr<CR><Bar>zM
```

How can I have both of them peacefully coexist in my .vimrc ?

- Is setlocal (for the second foldexpr) the solution ? Tried, failed…
- Is it possible to have a fold expression (the second one) apply only to two files (file1.txt, file2.txt) ?
- Is it possible to merge the 2 foldexpr in one ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option `foldexpr` is local to window, so:

- `:set` will establish both global and local values. Global value will be used as a default for subsequent windows where local value is not specified.
- `:setlocal` will determine local value only.

It's not clear to me what *merging the two expressions* would mean, but of course you can create a fold function containing all the complicated logic you want.

What is definitely easy is to set different values for `foldexpr` depending on the file (or file type). Use an autocommand for that.

So, the whole thing could be, in your .vimrc:

```
" Default: for all files
set foldmethod=expr
set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)=~'^\\s*$'&&getline(v:lnum+1)=~'\\S'?'<1':1
nnoremap <F8> :setlocal foldmethod=expr<CR><Bar>zM

" Only for specific files
augroup NonDefaultFoldMethod
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead file1.txt,file2.txt setlocal foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)!~@/
augroup end
```

The `augroup/autocmd!` idiom is there just to avoid duplicating autocommands if you source .vimrc repeatedly. It's best practice when establishing autocommands.

Comment: (it seems my previous comment has been eradicated) It works perfectly. Thank you.